# Echo 0 for Mysql query with no results

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I'm building an array of the number of calls I have for a particular client from a mysql db  on a running list of the last 30 days. The code I have so far works for adding the days that have calls to the array but I need a show a '0' for the days that have no calls (no entries in the db). Here is me code so far:

```
$query="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_db WHERE client_phone='clint_phone#' GROUP BY calldate"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);
    $data = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
       $data[] = $row[0];
    }
```

I just need a way to show if today I had 30 calls and yesterday I had 0, I need it to show [30,0]. What I have only would show [30].

EDIT * I have a mysql db will columns client_phone, calldate. Im looking to build a graph using the data in an array. Each point of the graph will represent a day and the number of calls for that client on that day. Im building the above query to populate that array. I'm trying to count backwards thirty days and feed the total calls for each day into the array.

EDIT 2* I've got it almost there. I'm getting a problem in the 'foreach' area. Below is the code with two print_r()'s to dump the array. The first one looks good, but the second one shows some array entries getting over-written that shouldn't be:

```
$query="SELECT calldate, COUNT(*) FROM my_db WHERE client_phone='phone#' and calldate>='20130101' AND calldate<='20130107' GROUP BY calldate ORDER BY calldate"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);
    $data = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      $data[$row['calldate']] = $row[1];
    }

$startDate = '20130101'; 
    $endDate = '20130107'; 
    $dates = array(); 

    for($current = $startDate; $current != $endDate; $current = date('Ymd', strtotime("$current +1 day"))) {
        $dates[] = $current; 
    }
    $dates[] = $endDate;  

print_r ($data);
echo "<br />";

foreach($dates as $date){
if (in_array($date, $data)) {
    // that date was found in your db_date array(therefore had queries)
}else{
$data[$date] = 0; //date was not found in your db_array so we set that date with no   queries to zero
}
}

print_r ($data);
```

I run this in a browser and I get this:

```
Array ( [20130101] => 1 [20130104] => 6 [20130105] => 2 [20130106] => 1 [20130107] => 3 ) 
Array ( [20130101] => 0 [20130104] => 0 [20130105] => 0 [20130106] => 0 [20130107] => 0 [20130102] => 0 [20130103] => 0 )
```

The top output looks good, just missing a zero assigned to dates not in the data[] array. The second array has zero's in the missing dates, but other overwrited that shouldn't have been.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I do not know what your database structure is so from my context I do not know what you mean by queries per day... is that one of the variables in the table? Please elaborate further. Do you mean that every date that is not in the array has no calls and you want to insert a 0 for each of those days into your array?

Comment: Can you show `my_db` structure and entries ?

Comment: You are saying that $data is your array with the keys as dates and the values as number of querys found in your database... You want for every date within that timespan that does not have a query to be put in the array with a value of zero?

Comment: Yes, I believe that is correct (sorry a little new).

Comment: @Milksnake12: I think I know how to do it but the code is pretty tricky... The basic idea is run this task; then create an array with every date in the span you want; then run a for loop saying if db_date not in data_array add db_date["date_array['date']"] = 0.

Comment: @Milksnake12: Ok I adjusted my solution and it should work; if not be really close. Sorry I could not run tests; but I do not have a db full of dates handy. Anyways if you can get that to run with your code please remember to check off it as a solution so people know it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finding every date that is in that timespan and doing a task for that does not really that standard of a solution. But depending if your host allows cron-tasks; if you were able to use cron tasks to automatically insert a 0 into your database at 11:59pm for that date if no querys were made that day; you could simply extract all dates.

If you do not want to do it with cron tasks I think you can manage it this way...

```
      $startDate = '2009-01-28'; 
        $endDate = '2009-02-04'; 
        $dates = array(); 

        for($current = $startDate; $current != $endDate; $current = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$current +1 day"))) {
            $dates[] = $current; 

        $dates[] = $endDate;  
    }
```

then do this

```
foreach($dates as $date){
if (array_key_exists($date, $data)) {
    // that date was found in your db_date array(therefore had queries)
}else{
$data[$date] = 0; //date was not found in your db_array so we set that date with no queries to zero
}
}
```

This may need some minor adjustments because I have not tested it; but this should work; if not something very close to it should. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm a little new to php, but I don't see how this adds a '0' to my array on the days that don't have any entries.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood what you meant, because from my perspective how your data in your table was handled was unclear.

Comment: Ok, I dont think the dates are set up to be the keys, when I run print_r() on the array I get Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 1 [2] => 3 [3] => 1) etc. Based on my first post, do I need to do something different to get the dates as keys?

Comment: @Milksnake12: Yeah, replace your $data[] = $row[0]; with
$data[$result['calldate']] = $row[0]; It may not be exactly like that but something similar, the basic idea is  $data[] makes index a key while $data[$date_value] makes the date value string the key.

Comment: Print_r just returns this with $data[$result['calldate']]: Array ( [] => 1 ). I tried $data[row['calldate']] as well with no luck. Is it because I'm using mysql_fetch_row?

Comment: Also noticed that I'm not calling 'calldate' in my sql query by name, do I need to?

Comment: @Milksnake12: Idk how your datatable is set up just call whatever field in your table that stores the date; then set that value within the brackets of $data[]

Comment: I got the dates to show as keys but the foreach part is causing me so trouble. I edited the main post to show where I'm stuck. Thanks for all the help by the way!

Comment: Are you having a problem executing the code or understanding it?
Basically foreach($dates as $date) means for every item in the "dates" array assign them a temporary value "date"... then in_array($date,$data) confirms if the value 'date' is in your array 'data'... and data[date] = 0  creates an array value in 'data' with key 'date' and value 0. No problem, I am glad to help; also please remember to check off my solution as the correct one.

Comment: Did you see the array outputs that I added to the main post? Those are what I'm confused with. Why The data[date] = 0 is running on dates that are already in the data array.

Comment: @Milksnake12: Ok I think I figured it out my previous example checked if the $date was a value in the $data array; but the dates are the keys in your data array... so I did array_key_exists($date, $data) which checks if the date is a key in your data array. That should work.